# Is "git diff --word-diff" ambigious with respect to newlines?

Tags: git, git-diff, word-diff

I am trying to parse git diff, and I am confident I am able to do so unambigiously with the plain command (no word-diff). I would like to include word-diff, but am having trouble understanding the rules, specifically in regards to new lines.

For example, plain diff might give me an output like this:

```
-﻿using LongNameSpace.LongMessages.InternalMessages.Amazon;
-using LongNameSpace.Voice;
+using System;
+using System.Collections.Generic;
+using System.Data;
+using System.Linq;
using NameSpace.Common.Enums;
```

While the same piece of code with word-diff=plain is:

```
[-﻿using LongNameSpace.LongMessages.InternalMessages.Amazon;-]using [-LongNameSpace.Voice;-]{+System;+}
{+using System.Collections.Generic;+}
{+using System.Data;+}
{+using System.Linq;+}
using NameSpace.Common.Enums;
```

My issue is with the first line of the word-diff version. Programmatically, how am I supposed to know that a newline is being removed as part of the first line at the end of the first `using`, and not that the first and second usings both shared the same line?

Comment: The `--word-diff` output is *not* suitable for use by additional programs. As you've seen, it makes lossy assumptions about what can be discarded.

Comment: @torek - not "lossy", but "greedy" IMHO?!

Comment: @torek Is there a suitable command that is smart enough to detect single "word" changes but is "lossless"? To rephrase, what command would the code review function in Bitbucket use?

Comment: Bitbucket probably have their own diff generator (since they used to run on Mercurial instead of Git).

Answer (score 0):

As [noted](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---word-diffltmodegt) in --word-diff doc

> By default, words are **delimited by whitespace**; see `--word-diff-regex` below.

and only using special (proper) --word-diff-regex you can add support of EOL as word-delimiters.

But yes, as @torek wrote, it doesn't help you with programmatic solution, --word-diff is "only for your eyes"